# Correct usage with compound nouns

Tags: nouns, american-english, british-english, compounds

1. He met an accomplished Hogwarts Witch Hermione Granger. (incorrect)

1'. He met an accomplished Hogwarts Witch, Hermione Granger.(correct)(accepting capitalisation)

2. He met a Witch Hermione Granger. (incorrect)
3. He met a Constable Ichabod Crane at court. (correct)

Why doesn't example 2 work like 3 without the comma?

Comment: I'm not sure that the third one is exactly correct. The use of "a Constable Ichabod Crane" suggests that there are several constables named "Ichabod Crane", one of which he met at court.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Constable' is part of the title in example (3). Compare

- (She married a Captain George Walters) ... (Here is Captain George Walters)

whereas 'w/Witch' hasn't been elevated to title status ... there is no compounding involving 'witch':

- (She married a teacher, Geoff Warner) ... (Here is a/that teacher, Geoff Warner)

With Bishop/bishop (and indeed Constable/constable, as KillingTime points out), you can choose whether to use the title or the position.

Positions / classifications (... a teacher, Geoff Warner // ... a bishop, Harry Carey // ... a witch [or Witch, as per JKR], Hermione Granger) are here shown in appositive constructions, and will need a comma, and usually uncapitalised (Rowling may capitalise as a 'race', as Tolkien does with 'the Dwarves are a secretive folk'. Note his irregular spelling too (though this is not a quote).)

Comment: Doesn't Constable function as a title or position in the same way as Bishop?

Comment: Yes, it may be used in the title, capitalised, or as an appositive (uncapitalised).